# React Native RadioForm adding initial state from Firebase

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to create an assessment sheet that keeps records of students skills.

I'm trying to use RadioForm in order to keep these records and easily edit them, but I dont seem to be able to set an initial value for radio form from my firebase data.

```js
   

<ListView
      enableEmptySections
      dataSource={ this.fonteDeDados }
      renderRow={data => { 
                                
      return(
                        
     <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' , width:300, borderWidth:1, borderColor:'#000' }}>
     <View style= {{backgroundColor:'#fff', padding:3, alignItems:'flex-start', justifyContent:'center', flex:1.5}}>
     <Text style={{margin:2}}>{data.criterio}</Text>
     </View>        
<RadioForm
 radio_props={[{label: 'Above', value: '0' },
 {label: 'Meeting', value: '1' },{label: 'Below', value: '2'}]}
 initial= {this.initial(this.props.caminho)}
 formHorizontal={true}
 style={{padding:10}}
 labelHorizontal={false}
 onPress={(value) => {this._clicaOption(data.criterio, value),  console.log(this.props.caminho)}}
                            />
                            
                            
                                 </View>
                         )
                         }}
                          />
```

My data read looks like this:

```js
Object {
  "Li4uY2FuIGdvIHVuZGVyd2F0ZXI=": Object {
    "N": Object {
      "Isabela": Object {
        "index": "0",
        "valor": "Above expectations",
      },
    },
    "PN": Object {
      "Clarissa": Object {
        "index": "0",
        "valor": "Above expectations",
      },
    },
    "criterio": "...can go underwater",
  },
  "Li4uY2FuIHN3aW0=": Object {
    "N": Object {
      "Isabela": Object {
        "index": "0",
        "valor": "Above expectations",
      },
    },
    "criterio": "...can swim",
  },
  "Li4uZW50ZXIgdGhlIHdhdGVyIHNhZmVseQ==": Object {
    "criterio": "...enter the water safely",
  },
}
```

caminho is define as this in mapStateToProps:

```js
let caminho = 'data.' + nomeGrupo + '.' + nomeAluno + '.index'
```

returning a path like this:

```js
data.PN.Clarissa.index
```

UPDATE:

I tried to use data[this.props.groupName][this.props.studentName].index, it works only if the path is already created in the database, if not the application crashes as an 'unefined object'

I'm a begginer in react native, would appreciate the help.

Regards